# How do i correctly reload my UICollectionView's data?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, reload

I have a function that is called in the viewDidLoad of my collectionView that loads content from my server into the view:

```
// Load Books Class
    func loadBooks() {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Books")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let bookObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
                for (index, object) in enumerate(bookObjects) {
                    self.books.append(Book(pfBook: object))
                }
            }else if let secondMessage = error?.userInfo?["error"] as? String
                where secondMessage == "The Internet connection appears to be offline." {
                    self.failedMessage(secondMessage)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            self.collectionView!.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my function that is called when the collectionView is refreshed, I basically am attempting to just reload the items back to the view:

```
func startRefresh(){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.loadBooks()

            println("loading complete!")

            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }

    }
```

However when I refresh, rather than loading the same content again, it loads twice the amount of content.. sort of like calling the load method on top of the load method, rather than re-executing it.. looking at my logic, what should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Well, what do you expect if you *append* all fetched objects to an existing array?

Comment: ahh yes.. you are right.. but how should i adjust this @MartinR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your array before you start adding items. Add `self.books.removeAll()` to your code, like following:

```
func loadBooks() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Books")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.books.removeAll()
            let bookObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
            for (index, object) in enumerate(bookObjects) {
                self.books.append(Book(pfBook: object))
            }
        }else if let secondMessage = error?.userInfo?["error"] as? String
            where secondMessage == "The Internet connection appears to be offline." {
                self.failedMessage(secondMessage)
        }
        self.collectionView!.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Edit: Since Parse callbacks are [executed on main thread](https://parse.com/questions/what-thread-does-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-complete-on), you don't need the `dispatch_async` part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove all children of `self.books` 
`self.books.removeAll()` before `self.books.append(Book(pfBook: object))`